# Cannot add marker dynamically with leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using Leafletjs library to create a visual sales module for my application. I can add marker with OnMapClick event but not with data coming from service.

```
    function onMapClick(e) {

        var newPosition = e.latlng;
        var field = GetFieldInfo();
        if (field) {
            if (bounds.contains(newPosition)) {

                AddMarkerToMap(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, field);

            }
        }
    }
```

Adding markers on map in AddMarkerToMap function.

```
    function AddMarkerToMap(_lat, _lng, field) {

        var lat = JSON.parse(_lat);
        var lng = JSON.parse(_lng);
        var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [lat, lng]
            }
        }

        var newMarker;

        L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

                newMarker = CreateMarker(lat, lng, field);

                return newMarker;
            }
        }).addTo(map);

        var lastValidPosition;
        newMarker.on("drag", function (event) {
            var latLng = newMarker.getLatLng();
            if (bounds.contains(latLng)) {
                lastValidPosition = latLng;
            } else {
                if (lastValidPosition) {
                    newMarker.setLatLng(lastValidPosition);
                }
            }
        }, newMarker);
        var popupContent = CreatePopupContent(field);
        newMarker.bindPopup(popupContent);

        newMarker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);
    }


    function CreateMarker(lat, lng, field) {
        var position = [lat, lng];
        var newMarker;

            newMarker = new customFieldMarker(position, {
                icon: L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'Sources/css/images/Outside-Chartreuse.png',
                    iconSize: [48, 48], // size of the icon
                    iconAnchor: [24, 48], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                    popupAnchor: [0, -48],
                }),

                draggable: "true",
                options: {
                    field: field
                }
            });

        return newMarker;
    }
```

In my code **field** is a JSON object coming from OData service and it contains lat,lng informations of markers that saved previously. Why markers added dynamically not shown on map ?

Comment: Why don't you load lat lng from `pointToLayer` callback function, it gives feature and geometry, you should reference from there.

Comment: I think problem is about geojsonFeature. Because I deleted L.geoJson block and added marker with only addto(map) it worked. Do you have any idea about this ? @Zhenyang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things don't make too much sense here:

1. Since you are using a service to load the feature, you should define the related events inside a service because it is async and there is no return.
2. `addTo(map)` should apply after the marker is created. The default `pointToLayer` callback only gives an option to utilize the feature attributes and geometry for you to create like infowindows, you should not use it for return a marker. A walkaround is as in below code -- you just consider it as a xhr call and get the data, and use if for only getting data and then use the response for the visualization. But Better way is to use native XHR call or Ajax call to get the data, and then use your addMarker function.

```js
function AddMarkerToMap(lat, lng, field) {

  var newMarker = CreateMarker(lat, lng, field);

  newMarker.addTo(map);

  var lastValidPosition;
  newMarker.on("drag", function(event) {
    var latLng = newMarker.getLatLng();
    if (bounds.contains(latLng)) {
      lastValidPosition = latLng;
    } else {
      if (lastValidPosition) {
        newMarker.setLatLng(lastValidPosition);
      }
    }
  }, newMarker);
  var popupContent = CreatePopupContent(field);
  newMarker.bindPopup(popupContent);

  newMarker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

  return newMarker;

}

function LoadFields() {

    var selectedFloor = $("#cmbFloors").val();
    if (selectedFloor && selectedFloor !== "0") {
      var serviceURL = "http://localhost/VisualSalesModuleWeb/FakeOrganizationData.svc";
      var ODataURL = serviceURL + "/ProductSet?$format=json&$filter=new_projectfloorid eq guid'" + selectedFloor + "'";

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ODataURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
          //ShowDialog();
          XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
          var fields = data.value;

          for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var field = fields[i];
            var lat = JSON.parse(field.Lattitude);
            var lng = JSON.parse(field.Longitude);
            AddMarkerToMap(lat, lng, field);
          }
        },
        error: function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorObject) {
          alert("OData Execution Error Occurred");
        },
        complete: function() {
          //HideDialog();
        }
      });
    }
    function GetAllMarkers() {

        var allMarkersObjArray = [];
        var allMarkersGeoJsonArray = [];

        $.each(map._layers, function (ml) {
            //console.log(map._layers)
            if (map._layers[ml].feature) {

                allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
                allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
            }
        })
      
        return allMarkersObjArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand my mistake clearly. But now I'm getting another error. This code adding markers to map but gives an error on L.geoJson  like this "Cannot set property 'feature' of undefined" @Zhenyang

Comment: just return something -- `return newMarker;`

Comment: Also I suggest you reorganize your `AddMarkerToMap` function, the arguments it takes are very confusing for the meaning of function itself since you decide to use L.GeoJSON. I recommend you just use native xhr or ajax call to get the json data, and then wrap your callback.

Comment: I returned newMarker but now it doesn't add marker to map. I'm getting my data with ajax call and its success event I'm looping my data. the loop is calling AddMarkerToMap function. @Zhenyang

Comment: Could you update the above scripts with your new logic?

Comment: I added a function named LoadFields. At top of edit it says "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." what should I do to show you my edit additionally ?

Comment: Actually at the beginning I used simple way to add marker like you did. But I needed to get markers and found a way that using geojson. I added a function named GetAllMarkers. As you can see I'm controlling layer has "feature". So how can I get markers when change geojson feature ? It's about 7 AM in Turkey and I didn't sleep this night because of this issue :)

Comment: I guess you can write a script to map your json to a GeoJSON format. But to just load the data in GeoJSON as marker directly, you need to call a class that inherit L.Marker Class. Your customFieldMarker is suspicious. What is that? I need to go to bed now. just leave a comment.

Comment: I added another FeatureGroup for markers and collected markers in it. Then worked on it. And created markers without GeoJSON because it is my first map/location based application so i'm not familiar with infrastructure of map system. Thanks for your help, I  learned lot from you :) @Zhenyang